# How to convert from latex to word / rtf / open office on Linux?

Tags: conversion, latex, rtf

I've installed OOoLatex (macro fails) 
I've installed latex2rtf - can't load the resume style (although latex plays with it nicely)

Help

Comment: Maybe PDF is an option?

Comment: How does oolatex fail, exactly? That's really your best bet. No other converter I'm aware of is going to be able to handle unusual .sty files. (Though I don't really imagine any of them are going to be able to convert a resume well.)

Answer (score 1):

**My halfhearted answer**

As I noted in a comment, I think you're best off trying to get oolatex to work. There are other conversion routines (the link below has links to many), but I don't know of any beyond oolatex that can handle arbitrary LaTeX packages.

**My real answer**

If the reason you're asking is because some potential employer is *insisting* on having your resume/CV in Word format, then I'd *definitely* follow the advice here: ["How Can I Convert Math-Less LaTeX Documents into Microsoft Word" (Stack Exchange); arjay's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-can-i-convert-math-less-latex-documents-into-microsoft-word/61#61).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe latex2rtf can't find the latex style files?  Try copying them into the same directory as the file that you are converting.

Comment: I had run:

latex CV

and I've got proper dvi

then, latex2rtf CV

CV.tex:3   Document format <res> unknown, using article format

CV.tex:3   Package/option 'margin' unknown.

CV.tex:3   Package/option 'line' unknown.

CV.tex:6   Unknown command '\name'

CV.tex:7   Error! Could not find <\end{resume}>

Comment: latex2rtf does decently well with normal text documents, but it doesn't really have the means for making use of special packages like this.